# Ошибка при запуске openvpn на windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

После запуска в логах появляется следующее:

> Wed Feb 06 12:33:03 2019 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
>   Options error: On Windows, --ifconfig is required when --dev tun is used
>   Use --help for more information.

Как исправить эти ошибки?